# How do I retrieve SMS Inbox messages on Symbian, preferably using j2me?

Tags: c++, python, qt, java-me

I want to create a mobile application that reads SMS messages from the phone and sends them to a server. I understand that j2me can't read SMS messages from the inbox folder. So this leaves with the option of using Symbian which am not conversant with.

My question is can I use j2me on Symbian and will I be able to achieve reading and sending of SMS messages to the server?

Secondly when programming symbian which is the approach to take?

1. QT
2. C++
3. python

Kindly assist me with links to materials that can help me get up to speed with this task.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you cant use J2ME to read from the inbox (not even on the Symbian platform). You can use the Symbian native API ([example](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Reading_SMS_from_Inbox)) or you could also use Qt (with [QtMessaging](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Read_and_send_SMS_messages_using_the_Qt_Messaging_API)).

You can also use Python to do all the same things. Its really just a matter of preference. You have a *little* bit more control using the C++ API but with Python, you get readability and simplicity. Nokia has great documentation regarding all of this ([even for the Python API](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_read_SMS_in_the_inbox)).

Hope this helps

Comment: i want to rephrase the question about how to read sms in symbian Mobile phones. i want to follow the path of using python to read sms in Symbian. please point me to articles to help me do this. could also assist me on using the ApiBridge to achieve the same functionality.